# How to implement autocomplete function for SVN repository?

Tags: bash, autocomplete, subversion

I generally use the SVN command line client to access my SVN repositories; however, I find it tedious to have to memorize the exact repository structure or iteratively use `svn ls` to find what I am looking for in the repository.

Since tabbing to autocomplete is essentially muscle memory when using any modern linux shell (BASH in my case) it seems very inconvenient that I cannot use tab to autocomplete SVN paths.

Is there a way to implement/enable this functionality which I am not aware of?

Comment: My fedora 23 subversion rpm comes with a set of completion functions for bash `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/svn*`.

Comment: Are you missing just basic completion (e.g. of svn command names) or are you looking for something more sophisticated (completing arguments for what commands?)?